# Diameter of a path

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Show that the diameter of the path of $k+1$ vertices (known as $P_k$) is $k$.

The following definitions are given:

A path of length $k$ in a graph $\Gamma$ is a graph map $\gamma : P_k \rightarrow \Gamma$.

For any two vertices $x$ and $y$ in $\Gamma$, the minimum length of a path between $x$ and $y$ is called the distance between $x$ and $y$.

$$\operatorname{diam}( \Gamma ) = \sup_{x,y \in V} d_\Gamma (x,y)$$

I'm just lost on what technique to use here.

Comment: I would have thought the diameter of $P_k$ is $k-1$. But maybe I don't understand your definitions. What is a "graph map"? What book are you using?

Comment: How do you define the length of a path?

Comment: Apologies bof. $P_k$ has $k+1$ vertices. Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Label the vertices of $P_k$ as $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{k+1}$, where the only edges are $(v_i, v_{i+1})$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$.  What is the length of the shortest path from $v_1$ to $v_{k+1}$?  What other vertices must this path include?  (Notice that if a path from $x$ to $y$ includes $u$ and $v$, then $d_\Gamma(u,v) \le d_\Gamma(x,y)$).